# Retrieve NSIndexPath of UICollectionViewCell with LongPressGesture in UICollectionView with section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i'm trying to retrieve the NSIndexPath of UICollectionViewCell using the UILongPressGestureRecognizer on a UIImageView on the Cell, sometimes works, exactly for the first item of the collection view, but when i scroll the UICollectionView, and i press on a cell retrieve me the first item of the UICollectionViewCell and not what i pressed, and in other case return nil, how i can do to fix this? this is the code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onLongPress:)];
        longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
        [cell.imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [cell.imgView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
...
}

-(void)onLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{

    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == gestureRecognizer.state) {
        NSLog(@"began");
        NSLog(@"%2.f %.2f",[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view].x,[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view].y);
        NSIndexPath *item = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view]];
        NSLog(@"%d - %d",item.row,item.section);
        MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:item];
        NSLog(@"%@",cell.myLabel.text);
      }
}
```

Comment: If `self.view != self.collectionView` then you should be using `locationInView:self.collectionView`

Comment: thank you very much it works, if you create an answer i can accept it :)

Comment: BTW, you might want to simply create one gesture recognizer that you attach to the `UICollectionView` itself, rather than to the individual images. Not only do you end up with far fewer gesture recognizers (and thus, possibly more efficient), but if you're not careful, your code can result in multiple gesture recognizers for cells that were successfully dequeued and reused (especially if using cell prototypes, in which it can be difficult to distinguish whether the cell was reused, or whether it instantiated a new one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `view` isn't the same instance as your `collectionView` then when you call `[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view]` you are getting a point in the wrong coordinate space. This will result in an inaccurate response when you ask for the index path.

So, you should be using

```
[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView]
```